# Highcharts - Turning on and off gridlines on show, hide, or legendItemClick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a multi-series column chart with multiple y-axes.  The y-axis is set such that only the first yAxis in the array has a gridLineWidth=1.  The rest are zero.

What I'm seeing is that if I hide all the series items whose yAxis has a [gridLineWidth](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis--gridLineWidth)=1, no gridlines show at all for the remainder of the series items (those that use the non-primary yAxis).  This makes sense since I've set their gridLineWidth's to zero...

So in an attempt to always show at least one set of gridlines, I decided to handle the [hide](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-events--hide) and [show](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-events--show) events on plotOptions.column.events (I also tried [legendItemClick](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-events--legendItemClick)) to first set all the gridLineWidth's to zero, and then look for the first visible series and set the gridLineWidth on it's yAxis object to 1, like so:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        ...
        events: {
            show: function (event) {
                var series = this.chart.series;
                var yAxes = this.chart.yAxis;

                // first hide all the gridlines
                _.each(yAxes, function (axis) { axis.gridLineWidth = 0; });
                var firstVisibleSeries = _.find(series, function (ser) { return ser.visible == true; });
                if (firstVisibleSeries != null) {
                    firstVisibleSeries.yAxis.gridLineWidth = 1;
                }
                this.chart.redraw();
            }
        },
    ...
    },
},
...
```

I'm using Underscore.js for the _.each() and _.find() methods.

Using firebug, everything looks good (meaning the gridLineWidth = 1 for the first visible series item and all others are set to zero at the end of the method execution).

But no matter what I do, including the this.chart.redraw() call I stuck in at the end in desperation, it doesn't appear to process my changes to the yAxis objects.  The gridlines are still missing if I hide all series items that use the first yAxis.

Am I doing something wrong - is there some final step i'm missing to make the changes permanent, or is there a different approach I can take to achieve this goal?

Thanks for your help

**EDIT:**

Here's a jsFiddle that presents the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmkuntz/7NEhU/2/

Hiding both 'money' type series shows the gridlines disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cailie on the [highslide](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17114) forum this is resolved.

From the post: I needed '.options' after the yAxis call:

```
firstVisibleSeries.yAxis.options.gridLineWidth = 1;
```

the base jsfiddle contains the fix:  http://jsfiddle.net/7NEhU/